# How to improve the performance of my low pass filter design

Tags: filter, low-pass, troubleshooting, lock-in-amplifier

**Goal:**
I am designing a low-noise, 8-pole, low pass filter to use in the output stage of a lock in amplifier. The filter needs to attenuate wide-band noise and a doubled carrier frequency in the range of 40 kHz to ~800 kHz. The higher the attenuation of the stopband is, the better.

**What I have tried:**
I used the TI online filter design tool (https://webench.ti.com/filter-design-tool/design/7) to create a 30kHz 8-pole Sallen-Key LPF. The schematic is included below in figure 1. I designed the filter in Eagle using ultra-low noise opamps ([LMH6626](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lmh6626.pdf)). The design schematic is included in figure 2, and the board layout in figure 3. I have assembled and tested the filter and am not getting the results I expected.

[image]
<sup>*Figure 1*</sup>

[image]
<sup>*Figure 2*</sup>

[image]
<sup>*Figure 3*</sup>

**The result I have achieved:**
I tested the circuit by feeding in a 1MHz BW noise signal and taking an FFT of the output. I found that the passband was severely attenuated in addition to the stop band. Further, there was a resonance peak in the stop band at around 250kHz.

**My questions:**

1. Am I doing something wrong in the design or implementation of this filter?
2. Why is the passband attenuated more than what is simulated? It should be a unity gain filter. Am I accidentally creating an attenuator by using the SMA connectors and cables? I thought that the opamps acted as a buffer.
3. Is there a different topology that you would recommend for this application?

Comment: Bell 103 FSK modem work, mark/space of 1270 Hz/1070 Hz and 2225 Hz/2025 Hz, required 10th order receive and 6th order transmit filters. The receive filter `wasn't fun` -- as in *hard* -- to get right. I don't know if you imagine `just ask TI and plug-and-play`. Maybe so. Maybe not. But I would be feeling especially diligent given past experience.

Comment: If you really want low noise design then you will need to change your resistor values. Some of your resistors have almost 10x (thermal) noise then your opamp...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The LMH6626 is not unity gain stable!

[image]

Comment: I can't believe I missed this thank you so much! I have been using it on a different project as a voltage follower ‍♂️.